# SQL Structure for Buildings with Amenities

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have a problem that I cannot seem to find a solution for. I have browsed similar answers around here, but nothing was exactly what I was looking for. I am fairly familiar with SQL, but not an expert by any means.

I have a table with information about apartment buildings - name, area, neighborhood, phone number, address, zip, etc. Currently, I have several amenities defined inside this table, such as "doorman", "elevator", "gym" (and few others) as tinyints to indicate whether the building does indeed have that amenity or not. However, I am in the process of incorporating many more amenity types and I figured that this might the time to change the structure as adding a column to a huge table of buildings does not make too much sense.

So I am looking for a solution that would provide me with the best ability to do the following:
1) search for a building based on user defined amenities (for example user selects that he wants to see buildings that must have a gym and a doorman, doesn't care about the others)
2) return the data about the building including all of the amenities that the building contains (for displaying information)

I was thinking about separating these structures into a many to many relationship and doing the following:
1) creating new table called "amenities" that would contain all of the amenities have the following structure:
    id -> unique id of the amenity
    name -> text description of the amenity
    value -> for example "pet_friendly" (for searching in forms, not sure if necessary)

2) creating a relationship table between buildings and amenities in another table called "building_amenities" with the following structure:
    id -> unique id of the relationship
    building_id -> refers to an id of a building
    amenity_id -> refers to an id of an amenity
    value -> tinyint, whether the building has the amenity or not
In this table each building would have a relationship to each amenity and indication whether it has it or not.

My problem is that I am not sure if this is the correct structure for this situation and I certainly have no clue how I would implement search queries if I had this structure.

Thanks a ton for any help with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you create a buildings table, an amenities table and a relational table. Each building has an ID, as does each amenity. To select all buildings with certain amenities present, you would simply write a query as follows

```
SELECT *
FROM (relational_table) rt JOIN (buildings_table) bt
    ON rt.id_building = bt.id_building JOIN (amenities_table) at
    ON at.id_amenity = rt.id_amenity
WHERE rt.id_amenity = ... (OR, AND etc.)
```

To return a building with its amenities you simply change the WHERE clause to WHERE id_building = x and then all the amenities should be selected in.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have everything except the tinyint flag in the building_amenities table. I'd only have records in that table if the amenities were actually there in real life.

That way, you can write a query to find all the buildings with a given amenity using a regular join:

```
select * from buildings
    join building_amenities on buildings.id=building_amenities.building_id
    join amenities on building_amenities.amenity_id=amenities.id
where amenities.name='doorman'
```

and if you want to get buildings without (say) doorman, you can use left joins:

```
select * from amenities
    left join building_amenities on amenities.id=building_amenities.amenity_id
    left join buildings on building_amenities.buildings_id=buildings.id
where buildings.id is NULL and amenities.name='doorman'
```

Comment: Sounds good, I wasn't sure whether to include it or not. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested by Phil Cairns you should not have the TINYINT (pseudo boolean) in the association table. There should only be a record in the association table if the amenity exists for the building.

Using multiple joins performs well but you can get the same ([or even slightly better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121680/sql-query-over-multiple-rows/10121774#10121774)) performance using GROUP BY ... HAVING COUNT and it is much easier to manipulate the query for multiple criteria.

So if you want to find all buildings that have amenities 1, 2 & 4 you could do -

```
SELECT b.*
FROM buildings b
INNER JOIN building_amenities ba
    ON b.id = ba.building_id
WHERE ba.amenity_id IN (1,2,4)
GROUP BY b.id
HAVING COUNT(ab.amenity_id) = 3
```

If you want to find all buildings with amenities 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 19 & 23 the query becomes -

```
SELECT b.*
FROM buildings b
INNER JOIN building_amenities ba
    ON b.id = ba.building_id
WHERE ba.amenity_id IN (1,2,4,7,13,19,23)
GROUP BY b.id
HAVING COUNT(ab.amenity_id) = 7
```

And if you need to display all the amenities for the building you can add a second join to the amenities table -

```
SELECT b.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ab2.amenity_id)
FROM buildings b
INNER JOIN building_amenities ba
    ON b.id = ba.building_id
INNER JOIN building_amenities ba2
    ON b.id = ba2.building_id
WHERE ba.amenity_id IN (1,2,4,7,13,19,23)
GROUP BY b.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ab.amenity_id) = 7
```

Comment: Thanks! With this search query, how would I go about returning all of the amenities that the building has? The user can search for buildings that must have specific amenities, but in the results, I would like to return information about the building that includes list of all of the amenities that the building has.

Comment: I have added another example including all the amenities for each building.